# How to add Excel formula to compare date with Today

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a EXCEL template of many sheets. There are two sheets whose data is depend on each other. I want to add overdue Column in sheet which compare date column of another sheet with Today if it is less than today then count it.
Here is the excel formula(s) that I have been trying but does not work.

> 1. =COUNTIFS('Task Worksheet'!A:A,C3,'Task Worksheet'!C:C,"In Progress",'Task Worksheet'!E:E,"<TODAY()")
> 2. =COUNTIFS('Task Worksheet'!A:A,C34,'Task Worksheet'!C:C,"In Progress",'Task Worksheet'!E:E,"<"&TODAY())

Here is the Excel Screenshots.

[image]
[image]

If you notice, **Brad Parsons shows 4 in Overdue but it should be 3**. because for Brad Parsons In Task Worksheet there are 4 rows for In Progress status but Overdue(s) is 3 but it shows 4.
I need help. The formula i used here is "if Task Worksheet **Assigned To(A)** equal To Current Sheet **Sales Rep** and Task Worksheet **Status equal(C)** In Progress and Task Worksheet **End Date(E)** is less than Today then count it. According to my logic for Brad Parsons Overdue column value should be 3. I spent alot to fix it but not succeed. Please Help me out.

Comment: Date Format of XLSX Template and System is "YYYY-mm-dd".

Comment: first, it should be `,"<"&TODAY())` as indicated in your 2nd formula. I can't see why it shouldn't work, can you try to switch the `<` to a `>` to see if you get 0 or 1 or any other number as result?

Comment: Are you sure? If you type `='Task Worksheet'!E2+1`, what does it say?

Comment: @tnavidi i tried  for "<"&TODAY()) gives me 0 for all rows and  change sign though but nothing reflects shows 0 for all rows.

Comment: @P.b E2 = 2021-12-03 when i type **='Task Worksheet'!E2+1** gives me **2021-12-04** add one day in End date.

Comment: If you type `=DATE VALUE(E2)` does that give a date, or error? If it returns a date (or 5 numbers for the Excel date) then your values are actual text. If it returns an error it means the value is already a date. In that case I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: @YogitaSharma if both `"<"&TODAY()` and `">"&TODAY()` gives 0, then the problem lies somewhere else because `"<TODAY()"` just compares to "TODAY()" alphabetically (i.e. the word "today"). You should check one column (one condition) at a time, and see which gives the unexpected result.